# Simple Imputer for imputing NaN values giving value error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working with the "House Prices - Advanced Regression Techniques" in Kaggle. I was trying to use SimpleImputer for filling NaN values.
But it shows some value error.

```
train_data['FireplaceQu']
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="most_frequent")
train_data.FireplaceQu = imputer.fit([train_data['FireplaceQu']])
train_data['FireplaceQu'] = imputer.transform([train_data['FireplaceQu']])
```

the value error is

```
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (1460)
```

But instead of last line if I give only

```
imputer.transform([train_data['FireplaceQu']]
```

it is running smoothly.

Comment: Please see how to create a [mcve] (which should be straightforward here, since the dataset is publicly available).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of line no. 3:

```
train_data.FireplaceQu = imputer.fit([train_data['FireplaceQu']])
```

As you are changing the values of the features before doing the transformation, your code should be like this instead of what you have written:

```
train_data['FireplaceQu']
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="most_frequent")
imputer.fit([train_data['FireplaceQu']])
train_data['FireplaceQu'] = imputer.transform([train_data['FireplaceQu']])
```